# Trying to get a value from the Current Session when using properties

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, inotifypropertychanged

I am pretty new to C#, so please go easy on me.

I have a major issue that been holding me up for days.

Problem:
We have a web application and use MVC4, when a document is opened, all the values in the model are created in the backingstore in session , by calling the method SaveValues()

```
public class NotifyPropertyChangedBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public Dictionary<string, object> BackingStore = new Dictionary<string, object>();
    public Dictionary<string, object> Changes = new Dictionary<string, object>();
    public bool HasChanges { get; set; }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;


    public void SaveValues()
    {
        // Expensive, to use reflection, especially if LOTS of objects are going to be used. 
        // You can use straight properties here if you want, this is just the lazy mans way.

        this.GetType().GetProperties().ToList().ForEach(tProp => { BackingStore[tProp.Name] = tProp.GetValue(this, null); Changes[tProp.Name] = ""; });
        HttpContext.Current.Session["SbackingStore"] = BackingStore;


        HasChanges = false;

    }

    public void RevertValues()
    {
        // Again, you can use straight properties here if you want. Since this is using Property setters, will take care of Changes dictionary.
        this.GetType().GetProperties().ToList().ForEach(tProp => tProp.SetValue(this, BackingStore[tProp.Name], null));
        HasChanges = false;


    }

    public void OnPropertyChanged(string propName, object propValue)
    {
        // If you have any object types, make sure Equals is properly defined to check for correct uniqueness.
        if (HttpContext.Current.Session["SbackingStore"] != null)
        {
            if (propValue == null) propValue = "";
            BackingStore = (Dictionary<string, object>)HttpContext.Current.Session["SbackingStore"];


            if (BackingStore[propName].Equals(propValue))
            { }
            else
            {
                Changes[propName] = propValue;
                HasChanges = true;
            }


            if (PropertyChanged != null)
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propName));
        }

    }

}
```

}

I have a class setup like so , which contains ;

```
public class VisitViewModel : NotifyPropertyChangedBase
{
    public Activity ActivityVM { get; set; }
    public VBSSteps VBSStepsVM { get; set; }
    public ProductTime ProductTimeVM { get; set; }
    public OtherPST OtherPSTVM { get; set; }
    public TimeRange TimeRangeVM { get; set; }
}
```

Each class that falls into the above VisitViewModel class and are coded like the below example. They inherit the NotifyPropertyChangedBase ( I will not post all the classes here as too much info ) ;

```
public class Activity : NotifyPropertyChangedBase
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string NotesID { get; set; }
    public string SubID { get; set; }
    public string Form { get; set; } // Form Name

    private string _custNumber;
    [MobileCRM.Resources.LocalizedString.LocalizedDisplayName("CustomerNumber")]
    [DataType(DataType.Text)]
    [Required]
    public string CustNumber
    {
        get { return _custNumber; }
        set { _custNumber = value; OnPropertyChanged("CustNumber", value); }
    }

    private string _companyName;
    [MobileCRM.Resources.LocalizedString.LocalizedDisplayName("CustomerName")]
    [DataType(DataType.Text)]
    [Required]
    public string CompanyName
    {
        get { return _companyName; }
        set { _companyName = value; OnPropertyChanged("CompanyName", value); }
    }
}
```

Now the issue is, the values that are created in the backing store ( session ) like the below ( when I expand any one of them i.e. ActivityVM, that contains the Keys and values I want. );

```
[0] {[ActivityVM, MobileCRM.Models.Activity]}
[1] {[VBSStepsVM, MobileCRM.Models.VBSSteps]}
[2] {[ProductTimeVM, MobileCRM.Models.ProdcutTime]}
[3] {[OtherPSTVM, MobileCRM.Models.OtherPST]}
[4] {[TimeRangeVM, MobileCRM.Models.TimeRange]}
[5] {[HasChanges, False]}
```

The problem with this is  the code I use to get the values and compare the changed data, cannot find the value as they are stored as propertys.... can anybody suggest a way around this ? 
Maybe when the values are saved, I could loop through each class and add all the values in each class to the backing store, therefore stopping the values being save as properties.

Code to get values from the backing store and perform the compare ( to see if the data has changed )

```
public void OnPropertyChanged(string propName, object propValue)
{
    // If you have any object types, make sure Equals is properly defined to check for correct uniqueness.
    if (HttpContext.Current.Session["SbackingStore"] != null)
{
    if (propValue == null) propValue = "";
    BackingStore = (Dictionary<string, object>)HttpContext.Current.Session["SbackingStore"];


    if (BackingStore[propName].Equals(propValue)) // Errors here : gives The given key was not present in the dictionary.
```

Comment: I would seriously reconsider the basic approach here... MVC is intended to be stateless, this is swimming against the stream. I also see serious problems with naming conflicts.

Comment: What can you suggest ?

Comment: Well, that would be to redesign your app... Why do you think you need to keep  all that state and if so why not use a MemCache ? What is your ORM ?

Comment: Hi.. We grab the data from webservices, then display it using MVC. I need to see what data has changed,this is because we use an approval process in another database (In lotus notes) that needs to see what feilds and values have changed. Once I have this data, I sent the data back via a webservice call. Hence why I need to see what data has changed and currently I am using this method ( which works, but not for this certain model as I have explained ). I know its not the best approach, but at this momment in time I am looking for a quick fix.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 0):

You have this code:

```
public void SaveValues()
    {
        // Expensive, to use reflection, especially if LOTS of objects are going to be used. 
        // You can use straight properties here if you want, this is just the lazy mans way.

        this.GetType().GetProperties().ToList().ForEach(tProp => { BackingStore[tProp.Name] = tProp.GetValue(this, null); Changes[tProp.Name] = ""; });
        HttpContext.Current.Session["SbackingStore"] = BackingStore;


        HasChanges = false;

    }
```

All clases inherit the base class with this method. So whenever you call SaveValues method on any of your derived classes the  HttpContext.Current.Session["SbackingStore"] get ovveriden with new backingstore, that is why you get "A key is missing in dictionary".

Comment: No, sorry thats not correct...... It deletes the backing store each time a document is opened, then creates a new backing store.... I am looking for a way to store the values in a different way instead of the way I mentioned above.... The values are there, but I have no idea how to get the values in each property...